# pycharm ignores command "integ()" from numpy.polynomial import Polynomialfunction / on jupyter it works

Tags: numpy, pycharm, polynomials

When using pycharm the integ() function is ignored:

```
from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial as P

p = P([1, 2, 3])

p.integ()

print(p)
```

outcome: `1.0 + 2.0 x**1 + 3.0 x**2` (no errors)

on jupyter
it gives me the correct result: ↦0.0+1.0+1.02+1.03

but I really prefer writing code on pycharm - can anyone tell me why this happens or how I could change it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that `p.integ()` doesn't change `p`.  It returns a new polynomial object.  When you execute `print(p)` after this expression, you are printing the original `p` that was created earlier.

In an interactive shell, with a line such as `p.integ()` that contains an expression (with no assignment), the shell (i.e. Jupyter) prints the value of the expression in the terminal. This is a feature of Jupyter, not of the Python interpreter.  When such an expression is encountered in a program, the Python interpreter evaluates the expression, but does not print it. If you want to print the integral of `p`, you can do something like

```py
q = p.integ()
print(q)
```

Comment: thx a lot - already the first part "note that p.integ() doesn't change p" of your answer was something I was not aware of until now ;) Your answer really helped to clearify!